# Integrating event loop from Ruby into C extension

Tags: c, ruby, linux, ipc

I'm wondering how can I integrate Ruby's event loop with a Ruby extension in C. I'm not sure if this is the right way for doing what I'm trying to do, so I'll explain the problem.

I'm using `msgrcv` and `msgsnd` (IPC) so send messages between a Ruby C extension and another application. The problem is that the extension method that receives the messages creates an infinite loop like this:

```
do{
    if(msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0){
        printf("Error");
    }else{
        rb_funcall(self, rb_intern("callback_method"), 1, rb_str_new2(rcvbuffer.mtext));
    }
} while(strcmp(rcvbuffer.mtext, "exit") != 0);
```

and that locks ruby's interpreter. I'd like to be able to call the receiver method in the Ruby extension without blocking.

How can this be done?

Comment: Where are `msgrcv` and `msgsnd` from? Is there an option for them to only check for a few ms, then continue? That would give you three conditions - error, process message, and "continue" - with a "continue" you either exit the loop and ensure it will be called again from controlling code, or have a reverse situation, with a "no message callback" which is called repeatedly whilst nothing is happening. If neither are possible for some reason, then running the message handling in a separate thread might work, but would be a bit of a headache, especially as you are already running async processes.

Comment: @NeilSlater msgrcv and msgsnd are standard kernel calls http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv I'd like to avoid threads.

Comment: I think you want to set the `IPC_NOWAIT` flag, catch the resulting error when there is no message to process by handing control back to the main script (i.e. assing error num to a variable and check it where currently it just has `printf("Error")`). That can either be a "no message" callback - similar to your message handling one - or returning form the extension in the expectation the main code will call again when it is ready to process messages. Which you want depends on the structure of containing code.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, this assumes you want to call some method (which obviously you need to implement) on the class when there is no message:

```
do{
    if( msgrcv( msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, IPC_NOWAIT ) < 0) {
        // Handle error conditions
        if ( rcvbuffer.errno == ENOMSG ) {
          rb_funcall(self, rb_intern("no_msg_callback_method"), 0);
          // Or you could simply  . . .
          // break;
        } else {
          printf("Error");
        }
    }else{
        rb_funcall(self, rb_intern("callback_method"), 1, rb_str_new2(rcvbuffer.mtext));
    }
} while(strcmp(rcvbuffer.mtext, "exit") != 0);
```

Your other option is to set a flag and allow the loop to exit when there are no messages. Then the method caller needs to determine whether it has received an "exit" message (which is sent to `callback_method` as well), or has no messages to process currently, so can do something else.

Comment: Thank you, but there is still one major problem. Messages arrive all the time (around 50/s) so the loop won't exit ever. I need a way to call that block of code in my C extension from Ruby in a non-blocking way. Something like MyModule::start_receiving_msgs() \n puts "Receiving messages!" <---- so I'd really start receiving messages and see the puts.    EDIT: Oh, and I'd really like to avoid threads.

Comment: In that case, don't use an infinite `while` loop - use a `for` loop or even no loop at all. The loop is there assuming that the main purpose of your code is is to process messages. I would be concerned that the amount of traffic you are expecting it to handle means that messages would back up very quickly, so it cannot be doing very much else - e.g. assuming your message handling took 5ms, that gives you just 15ms of processing (on average) to do whatever else the script is supposed to do between handling messages.

Comment: I need a loop somewhere, in the extension or in my ruby code, in order to receive all messages. The problem is that if I place it in the extension, I'm blocking the rest of the script, and if I place it in the ruby script, I can't do anything else (or can I?). I'm not sure if I can create something like: loo for 10ms, schedule next loop in 50ms, do stuff, call the scheduled loop. Something like alarms in Javascript. Is that possible?

Comment: @alexandernst: That is not really possible without using threads. However, you might find a Ruby wrapper that will handle some of the complexity of this requirement (`eventmachine` could be useful?). If you scheduled loops at 17% of total time as you suggest, and then need to process incoming 50 msg/sec, each message would need to process each message in ~4ms, otherwise the queue will grow faster than you pop messages off it. This is do-able of course, but if your message handling code can *already* perform that well, then it *will* exit reliably anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll have another look at eventmachine. Anyways, a quick google search told me that EV is bad and should be avoided. How true is that?

Comment: I don't know. `eventmachine` is used in `thin` web server, which is why I thought of it. Other Ruby libraries could well be available and suit your goals better. You also want to avoid pre-optimising - I think perhaps you have an "outer" unstated problem here you are trying to optimise, that makes it difficult to solve your main issue in the way you want or expect. Perhaps post a new question more focused on your goals for app as whole (instead of this specific loop)?

Comment: Maybe yes, anyways, the entire project is really complex. It involves sending data from a kernel module to userland, ncurses, ruby... I'll probably create another question. Thank you for the help here! :)